# to show image in large size with fancybox

Tags: plugins

its my first time to do work with wordpress , now I am wanted to show some images in my site with fancybox.when I click images then show in some big size, for this I read some document,install plugin and activate, but no popup box is open, so I want to  know what is the easiest and correct way to do this, thanks.

and 1 more thing, In my site first I install wordpress then I am using Chamber theme in it, and 2 other theme all already there, so when i paste the fancybox folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Easy Fancybox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/) by RavanH. I use it on all of the sites I work on. It automatically add fancybox functionality to images, so there is minimal work required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about popup box (e.g. shadowbox or lightbox) than easiest way to do is download plugin called "Shadowbox JS" for dark and "Lightbox" for light theme. infact if you are familiar with css than can change look and feel.

But only thing is plugin will apply to all images and big images pops up with box.

I am using now Jquery Lightbox
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-balupton-edition/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nextgen gallery plugin which will have the all option like fancybox lightbox and slide show.once activate the plugin go to the setting gallery options page and select fancyb[enter link description here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-ngg-with-fancybox-plugin)ox option in drop down that will work....